# Resistance is futile, Resistors have been dispatched to model your Resistance

Tags: beginner, haskell, community-challenge

Since it was getting boring to always do OOP Languages I decided to dabble in the functional realm of programming.

For that I chose the narrowly missed [community-challenge by Edward: Resistor Mania](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3791/37660), since it really is a quick-to solve using recursive and functional style.

**Challenge description:**

> In electronics, two resistors in series have a combined resistance
>   \$R_1+R_2\$, and two resistors in parallel have combined resistance of
>   \$\displaystyle \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\$.  Given an infinite supply
>   of \$270\Omega\$ resistors with \$5\%\$ tolerance, write a program to
>   describe how to combine them into any arbitrary resistance value.

To make things a little easier for me, I decided to ditch the tolerance for this first prototype. Instead of \$270\Omega\$ I also ask the user to provide the values for our resistors.

The code works as expected for rather simple inputs, and I didn't check for more complicated stuff yet.

The ouptut comes as a wiring help that uses simple "equations" to describe parallel and combining wiring.

Output of some manual tests:

> ```
> *Main> resistor_mania 60 120
> "60.0+60.0"
> *Main> resistor_mania 120 60
> "120.0||(120.0)"
> *Main> resistor_mania 120 120
> "120.0"
> ```

#### Code:

```
module Main where

import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering;
    putStrLn "Please enter the value of resistors we use";
    res_input <- getLine;
    putStrLn "Please enter the value you want to model with these resistors";
    target_value <- getLine;
    putStrLn (show (resistor_mania (read res_input) (read target_value)));


{-
Calculate the remaining resistor-strenght necessary to get to a given target
 when going in parallel to the given existing resistor.
-}
p_resistor :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
p_resistor = (\existing target -> (1 / ((1 / target) - (1 / existing))));

{-
Resistor_Mania: Create a wiring schema for a given target resistor value
with one single available kind of resistor
-}
resistor_mania :: (Show a, Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> String
resistor_mania resistor target =
    if resistor == target;
    then (show resistor);
    else if resistor < target;
    then (show resistor) ++ "+" ++ (resistor_mania resistor (target - resistor));
    else (show resistor) ++ "||(" ++ (resistor_mania resistor (p_resistor resistor target)) ++ ")";
```

There's quite a few things that I hope can be improved here. For one I don't like how `p_resistor` is declared as a lambda, and `resistor_mania` isn't.
Another thing I don't like is the concatenation of Strings in the control structure and the type-signature of `resistor_mania` makes me uneasy :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Guards**

Using so many `if` `then` and `else` is really weird in Haskell, I suggest using the guards:

```
resistor_mania resistor target
    | resistor == target = (show resistor)
    | resistor < target = (show resistor) ++ "+" ++ (resistor_mania resistor (target - resistor))
    | otherwise = (show resistor) ++ "||(" ++ (resistor_mania resistor (p_resistor resistor target)) ++ ")"
```

This is the standard way of listing mutually exclusive conditions in a function definition.

**Semicolons**

[Haskell uses a two-dimensional syntax](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html#Layout), semicolons are not needed and should be omitted as they convey no additional information, just noise.

**Prefer mainstream function definitions**

```
p_resistor = (\existing target -> (1 / ((1 / target) - (1 / existing))))
```

Becomes:

```
p_resistor existing target = (1 / ((1 / target) - (1 / existing))))
```

That looks maybe less cool, but surely faster to understand.

**Types**

> the type-signature of resistor_mania makes me uneasy :/

Haskell is type-centric, so it is good that you are worrying about types.

I deleted your types and asked the compiler what types it would like for your functions.

```
*Main> :t p_resistor
p_resistor :: Double -> Double -> Double
*Main> :t resistor_mania
resistor_mania :: Double -> Double -> String
```

I think these suggested types are simpler, and I would use them instead of your bulky type declarations.

**Non-closing parenthesis**

`$` is like a parenthesis but you do not need to close it:

```
putStrLn $ show $ resistor_mania (read res_input) (read target_value)
```

This is somewhat subjective though...

Comment: Also, `1 / ((1 / target) - (1 / existing))` is likely easier understood as `(target * existing) / (existing - target)`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of guards, I would use

```
resistor_mania resistor target = case compare resistor target of
    EQ -> show resistor
    LT -> show resistor ++ "+" ++ resistor_mania resistor (target - resistor)
    GT -> show resistor ++ "||(" ++ resistor_mania resistor (p_resistor resistor target) ++ ")"
```

This is like a switch statement. Looking at it, I see the further refactoring of

```
resistor_mania resistor target = show resistor ++ case compare resistor target of
    EQ -> ""
    LT -> "+" ++ resistor_mania resistor (target - resistor)
    GT -> "||(" ++ resistor_mania resistor (p_resistor resistor target) ++ ")"
```

Since resistor never changes, you could do

```
resistor_mania resistor = go where
    go target = show resistor ++ case compare resistor target of
        EQ -> ""
        LT -> "+" ++ go (target - resistor)
        GT -> "||(" ++ go (p_resistor resistor target) ++ ")"
```

`readLn` instead of `getLine` will read the line for you after getting it. I also recommend the above use of `$`. (That's actually just an operator of type (a -> b) -> a -> b which applies the function on the left to the argument on the right; it has lowest operator precedence, so it's handy for avoiding parentheses.) Yes, that lambda (`\`) is unnecessary.

For fun, you could replace the () by $ in the output. Then you could actually implement this in terms of unfoldr:

```
resistor_mania resistor = supersperse (show resistor) .: unfoldr $
    \target -> case compare resistor target of
        EQ -> Nothing
        LT -> Just (" + $ ", target - resistor)
        GT -> Just (" || $ ", p_resistor resistor target)

(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(f .: g) x = f . g x

supersperse :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
supersperse xs xss = xs ++ intercalate xs xss ++ xs
```

Comment: aaaand I've got no idea what you're doing there in the last code-block. I think there is an explanation, but... I have no clue what the heck happens there... also I'm not sure how the output changes you mention are helping me :/